# How to use next() to traverse array(NULL=>NULL, FALSE=>FALSE) in PHP

Tags: php

How can I use `next()` to traverse the array like this in PHP:

```
$a = array(NULL=>NULL, FALSE=>FALSE)
```

This kind of code will not work:

```
reset($a);
while (key($a)) {
    print "a";
    next($a);
}
```

Comment: That I know of you can't.

Comment: @Gumbo, I am just curious if I can use `next()` to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check [the manual of next()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), you will see this.

> You won't be able to distinguish the end of an array from a boolean
> FALSE element. To properly traverse an array which may contain FALSE
> elements, see the [each()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) function.

Here is a workaround:

```
$fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');

reset($fruit);
while (list($key, $val) = each($fruit)) {
    echo "$key => $val<br>";
}
```

You could also try [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
$fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');
foreach($fruit as $key => $val){
    echo "$key => $val<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it like this:

```
foreach ($a as $value ) {
 print $value
 }
```